# identify that the text in autocomplete ajax textbox is one of strings in the autocomplete string list

Tags: ajax, list, autocomplete

in ajax autocomplete textbox, i can select one of the names in the autocomplete list.
but what if the user types the text himself and doesn't select one of the items in the autocomplete list?
i need to identify that the user entered a text that is similiar to one of the items.

So i thought of checking the text inside the textbox with every chenge in the textbox characters, but then i will have to compare it with the items in the list, 
do i have access to the items in the autocomplete list from the JS or Code behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you usually do a new request for every character typed in if you have a database from which you will take the completions, if that's the case you could just keep doing the request until you only get one result form the query and that should be the closest one. If you end up having no results when the user has finished typing then do the search he wanted to do?

To answer your question you usually have access to it from the server-side, ie a php script.

Comment: thank you , i'm looking for a better solution because asking the DB every character inserted will slow the application down....

Comment: Yeah, i kinda figured. Perhaps you could try to load everything into the js or do some kind of caching?